# How to score an exam grade

Tags: r

my `df` is:

```
--ID   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 
1 112   A  B  C  D  A  D  C
2 222   E  B  C  A  A  D  C
3 342   D  C  C  A  D  C  D
4 454   A  B  D  E  C  B  A
5 554   A  A  C  A  A  D  D
6 136   B  A  D  A  E  D  A
```

I have my solution:

```
solution= c(0, A, B, C,A, D, D, A)
```

I wanted to know if there was `score` function that I  could use to see how many right answers they got compared to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

We can try `rowSums` after creating a logical matrix

```
rowSums(df[-1] == solution[col(df[-1])])
#1 2 3 4 5 6 
#4 4 3 3 4 3
```

#### data

```
solution <-  c('A', 'B', 'C','A', 'D', 'D', 'A')
```